# Simple but effective face detection algorithm using neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

I'd like to have my undergrad machine learning students have the option of doing a face detection project using neural networks (constructed by the students using Keras). The algorithm should ideally be simple but able to detect faces in a group photo of our class. From what I've seen so far, implementing YOLO or R-CNN looks too complicated, and I think a simpler approach should be possible because YOLO and R-CNN are near state of the art and they do more than just face detection.

Any recommendations for a relatively simple face detection algorithm that could be used?

Comment: You can use Siamese networks ->  https://link.medium.com/xrCQOD8ntV

Answer (score 2):

Relatively trivial approach to object (face) detection is to train a (convolutional) neural network to perform binary classification (face vs. no face) on image patches. Then you can pass patches of the tested image in a sliding window fashion (using certain stride for improved speed) to the network and see if it has detected a face in that region of the tested image. Finally, to handle various sizes of faces, you can process the tested image on several different scales.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think would be a good training dataset to use to train the binary classifier (face vs. no face) ?

Comment: quick Google search produces e.g. this one: https://www.kaggle.com/dataturks/face-detection-in-images